# Убрать элементы интерфейса текущего окна

Tags: window.open, javascript, privacy

Здравствуйте.

Никак не получается убрать элементы интерфейса текущего окна. Вот код, который не срабатывает (Firefox 36.0):

```
if (window.locationbar && ...) {
    window.locationbar.visible = !window.locationbar.visible;
    window.menubar.visible = !window.menubar.visible;
    //и т.д.
}
```

Пробовал также открыть окно при помощи window.open(), и затем закрыть старое, новое открывалось корректно, но старое не закрывалось. Пробовал разные типа фиксы, вроде `window.open('', '_self', '')` и т.д. Закрытие не срабатывало.

Пытался также сделать скрипт привелегированным, чтобы дать разрешение на использование способа в коде выше, но не было такого свойства у firefox.

```
try {
    if (window.netscape && netscape.security) { // Firefox
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
    }
}
catch (e) {
    alert ("UniversalBrowserWrite privilege is required in Firefox!");
    return;
}
```

Еще нашел, что нужно было в about:config или через pref установить:

```
pref("signed.applets.codebase_principal_support",true);
pref("capability.principal.codebase.p0.granted", "UniversalXPConnect UniversalBrowserRead UniversalBrowserWrite UniversalPreferencesRead UniversalPreferencesWrite UniversalFileRead UniversalFileWrite");
pref("capability.principal.codebase.p0.id", "http://localhost");
```

Потом только узнал, что начиная с 17 версии firefox PrivilegeManager был удалён и дальше больше, сейчас уже нет capability вообще, то есть как разрешить эти привилегии, непонятно.

Уважаемые форумчане, может, кто знает еще лазейку или, может, у кого-то работает в последней версии firefox то, что я делал, и значит, я что-то не так сделал.